# What do the numbers in the intersection Matrix in the JTS TestBuilder mean?

Tags: jts-topology-suite

[image]

What do the numbers in the intersection Matrix in the JTS TestBuilder mean?

Comment: I guess that the dimensionality of the intersection. 0=point, 1=line, 2=area, F=nothing.

Answer (score 3):

This is described in the JTS [Javadoc](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/IntersectionMatrix.html), and also on the Wikipedia [entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM#Matrix_model).